# How do you increase the typewriter effect speed? And increase cursor size?

Tags: javascript

I successfully added this plugin: https://safi.me.uk/typewriterjs. 
I was able to adjust the deleting speed, but am not sure how to adjust the actual typing speed?
Additional, I'd like to make the blinking cursor a little larger than my actual **font/text** size.

1. How do I add/write the typing speed to js?
2. How do I change the blinking cursor size?

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you.

Mike

Comment: Can you show us some of your code, so that we can help you?

Comment: Yes.  I will be back to my computer in 20mins.  Thank you!

Comment: for the blinking cursor size, use CSS: .Typewriter__cursor{font-size:your-size-here}

Comment: Actually, if you clicked the link above you’ll see the js code I copied.  If you want to wait, I’ll paste the code here in about 20mins.  I appreciate your help. - Mike

Comment: @imvain2 thank you!!

Comment: Also, I think that `delay` is the option to control the speed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to add in two additional options.

**delay** - controls the rate of the cursor

**cursorClassName** - controls the class to apply to the actual cursor.

With delay, you are setting it in milliseconds.

For the cursorClassName you basically just need to create a css class, set the size and do really whatever else you want.

Additionally you would append this inside of the Typewriter constructor.

Example:

```js
var app = document.getElementById('app');

var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {
    loop: true,
    delay: 1000, // SET TO USE A 1 SECOND DELAY
    cursorClassName: 'cursorSize' // SET TO MY CUSTOM CLASS NAME
});

typewriter.typeString('Hello World!')
    .pauseFor(2500)
    .deleteAll()
    .typeString('Strings can be removed')
    .pauseFor(2500)
    .deleteChars(7)
    .typeString('<strong>altered!</strong>')
    .pauseFor(2500)
    .start();
```

```css
.cursorSize {
  font-size: 75px; /*Setting this to a ridiculous size as an example*/
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/TypewriterJS/1.0.0/typewriter.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

In the above snippet you will see I set a ridiculous size for the cursor. That is on purpose. I also made it red and italic so you can see that it is really being updated.

As for the delay, I did a 1 second delay but heck make it as fast or slow as you'd like.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  Your help was greatly appreciated.

Comment: No worries @MikeAllen

Comment: hey thanks again!  I got the delay speed, delete speed, and cursor perfect!  Another quick question if you don't mind?  After the text deletes, the next sentences begins immediately with no pause.  Is there a way to add a pause before the next sentence types out?   As in when the text deletes, I'd like the cursor to just blink and pause a bit before the next sentence types out.. your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs - https://safi.me.uk/typewriterjs/ - it looks like the 'delay' option can be used to set the typing speed. It's less clear about the cursor size although the 'cursor' option can be used to set a custom cursor.

Comment: Yes, delay and deleteDelay options can be used. The default however is natural which will pick a random delay from 120 to 160ms. If this should be still random but faster you would have to change the random interval here: https://github.com/tameemsafi/typewriterjs/blob/master/src/core/Typewriter.js#L496 (I guess if you want to make it very fast there is no need for random and you can just specify `delay: 80`